# Project Euler #22 with Golang; returns different result every time

Tags: go

I am doing problem 22 of Project Euler with Go, which I am new to, and my code gives me inconsistent results meaning every time I run the program it shows a different result. It is always very close to what I have seen is the correct answer but ranges around within several hundred points. I originally thought it may have been due to float rounding inaccuracy but I have checked and that is not the case(I think). 
I would really appreciate it if someone could point out what may be going on that would cause this. I have struggled to find the problem with my code for several days and have not been able to solve it or even find similar issues on forums.
As a side note I originally wrote this using the golang math/big package and was getting the same changing results.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math"
    "strings"
)

func openFileReturnSlice(f string) []string {
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to read file: p022_names.txt")
    }
    s2s := strings.Split(string(bytes), "\"")
    s22 := strings.Join(s2s, "")
    names := strings.Split(s22, ",")
    return names
}

func alphabetize(n []string) ([]string, map[string]int) {
    wordsValues := make(map[string]float64)
    wordLetterVal := make(map[string]int)
    for _, s := range n {
        loop := -1
        var wordValue float64
        alpha := int(0)
        for _, l := range s {
            ell := int(l) - 64
            mvDec := math.Pow(100, math.Abs(float64(loop)))
            wordValue += float64(l) / mvDec
            alpha += ell
            loop--
        }
        wordsValues[s] = wordValue
        wordLetterVal[s] = alpha
    }
    var sortedNames []string
    lenWordValues := len(wordsValues)
    for i := 0; i < lenWordValues; i++ {
        var lowValName string
        lowVal := float64(10)
        for k, v := range wordsValues {
            if v < lowVal {
                lowVal = v
                lowValName = k
            }
        }
        delete(wordsValues, lowValName)
        sortedNames = append(sortedNames, lowValName)
    }
    return sortedNames, wordLetterVal
}

func main() {
    names := openFileReturnSlice("p022_names.txt")
    alphabetical, sumAlphaValues := alphabetize(names)
    var total int
    for k := 0; k < len(alphabetical); k++ {
        var temp int
        key := k + 1
        temp = sumAlphaValues[alphabetical[k]] * key
        total += temp
    }
    fmt.Println("The total is: ", total)
}
```

Comment: Go intentionally randomizes map entry order. Is it possible that your range over wordsValues might be coming up with different lowVal and lowValName, depending on the order?

Comment: I am not sure how that could be a problem unless the range over wordsValues randomly called duplicates. I suppose I could range over the original slice and explicitly call the value for that name stored in wordsValues to rule it out. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: The first thing to do is to compile the program without errors: `25:9: k declared and not used`.

Comment: I tried hardcoding the text file and am not seeing any variation in answers. I'm not sure it's producing the correct answer (the answer it's producing ends in 928) but it is consistent.

Comment: peterSO, fixed. k Was used by a Println that was used for debugging but was removed and I forgot to fix before copy and pasting.

Comment: user2027202827 that number sounds correct but I am unsure by what you mean "hardcoding".  I tried just now tried coding the contents of the file as a string literal and I am still getting the same changing result.

Comment: It sounds like others have already identified the problem but I just meant that I created an array of the names instead of reading them from a file.

Answer (score 4):

The use of floating point is suspicious, it's imprecise. The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next. Your use of maps is the most likely explanation for seemingly random behavior.

---

The first question to ask is: What is the right answer?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func readNames(f string) []string {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s := string(bytes.Replace(b, []byte(`"`), []byte(``), -1))
    return strings.Split(s, ",")
}

func totalScores(names []string) int64 {
    for i := 0; i < len(names); i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(names); j++ {
            if names[i] > names[j] {
                names[i], names[j] = names[j], names[i]
            }
        }
    }

    total := int64(0)
    for i, name := range names {
        score := int64(0)
        for _, char := range name {
            score += int64(char - 'A' + 1)
        }
        score *= int64(i) + 1
        total += score
    }
    return total
}

func main() {
    names := readNames("p022_names.txt")
    total := totalScores(names)
    fmt.Println("The total is: ", total)
}
```

Output:

```
The total is:  871198282
```

This is how Project Euler expected you to write the first version of your solution. Your second version should replace the simple selection sort with a faster sort, like Quicksort.

For example, your program takes a long time to produce the wrong result:

```
The total is:  871197995
real    0m1.945s
user    0m1.944s
sys     0m0.004s
```

My program produces the correct result and is faster:

```
The total is:  871198282
real    0m0.771s
user    0m0.768s
sys     0m0.004s
```

If we replace my selection sort with a Go sort:

```
sort.StringSlice(names).Sort()
```

The revised program produces the correct result and it's much faster:

```
The total is:  871198282
real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Project Euler, Names scores, Problem 22 is about fast sort algorithms, not about the trivial calculation of scores.

---

For a stable result from your code, comment out the `delete` statement:

```
// delete(wordsValues, lowValName)
```

Now you are left with the floating-point error: [Floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) and [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

---

Your algorithm creates approximate, non-unique floating-point `wordValue`s. Therefore, the random iteration over the map may choose some different `lowVal` and `lowValName` pairs and different map entries may be deleted.

Non-unique `wordValue`s:

```
0.657666698284738
0.6576697465786885
0.6576697465786885
0.6576698865786884
0.6578786577658275
0.6578847978698485
0.658571858384738
0.6669827865826875
0.6765847269827377
0.676976698384738
0.677282738384698
0.6772827383847367
0.6772827383847367
0.677282738384738
0.677282738384738
0.6772827383847982
0.6776697769788476
0.6982786983847379
0.6986657871697675
0.7076798269786776
0.7076798269788476
0.7082657867698368
0.7082657867738368
0.7082696869827366
0.7082696869827366
0.7165668273697676
0.716979827169658
0.7169798271698486
0.716979827173658
0.716979827173658
0.716979827173658
0.7185737676698277
0.7269788273698486
0.7273766869716582
0.7465678185697674
0.746567818569769
0.746567818569769
0.7469657878698486
0.7479836980727379
0.7565847265827377
0.7565847269827377
0.7573776669827669
0.7765716865766978
0.7765826769767379
0.7765826769767379
0.7765827165826985
0.7765827165826985
0.7765827165826985
0.7765827165826985
0.7765827165827385
0.7765827165827385
0.7765827185698275
0.7773677269767378
0.827983657673787
0.8384698072657875
0.8472797765837379
0.8665766978847378
```

Comment: peterSO (and abhink below), your solution is certainly more compact and (more importantly) accurate, but is there a solution to using the method I was trying? I was challenging myself to do the alphabetizing and this seemed the most direct route. As I mentioned I had also written this using big numbers package but was met with the same issue. Is there any way to correct the floating point inaccuracy problem?

Comment: Also, no disrespect intended, but I don't really see how the order of iteration over a map in the way that I am using it would be problematic. I am only looking for the lowest value stored in the map and not relying on order in any way. It gives me a convenient way to access both the value and the string. Once again, intend no disrespect, just would like to understand how the use of maps could be problematic in this example.

Comment: @StephenAdams: Your `float64` `wordValue` algorithm is hopelessly flawed: [Floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). Keep it simple and use an `int64` algorithm.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to break it down for me. I realize that you and most everyone on this forum likely have much more experience then I and these really are trivial and routine exercises. For most, project euler probably is a place to work on optimization. For me however, with about 17 days of experience with go and limited experience with coding project euler is a great place for me to practice these mundane tasks. I could easily have googled the correct solution and been done and never be able to remember it when it mattered but I choose to do it the hard, ugly, slow way.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct about the fault in your code being related to floating point numbers. Take these two names for example:

```
["BERNARDINE", "BERNARDINA"]
```

If you simply run your code on this input set, you get the following value for `wordsValues`:

```
map[BERNARDINE:0.6669827865826875 BERNARDINA:0.6669827865826875]
```

As you can clearly see, both these keys map to same value due to loss in floating point number precision. And as it has already been mentioned that map iteration order is [randomized](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) in Go, it is possible that your sorting algorithm is producing incorrect result (some iteration may put `BERNARDINE` before `BERNARDINA` since both will have same values).

Since `float64` supports up to 15 significant digits, names having more than 8 characters could spell trouble.

The best solution is to use pre-existing sorting procedure as already detailed by @peterSO above.